# why html tags does't work and show as string value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to ask advice from you guys since I have a problem of showing html tags within table structure.
Actually, I want to show is "link".
To be clear I will explain you more details.

I am making auto generated table structure view with the help of **javascript** and **jquery** that shows data from database and want to show these data as table structure which also include the link that allows user to edit the data. That's it.

See the below image:
[image]

As you can see, links are showing as normal characters.
So anyone who knows the answer please advice me.

Below is the code:

```
//php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM v_category";
        $dbaction = new db_action($sql,'G');
        $result = $dbaction->db_process();
        $dataRows = "Category Name|Remark|Edit|";

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $ctgr_id = $row["ctgr_id"];
                $ctgr_name = $row["ctgr_name"];
                $remark = $row["remk"];
                $link = "<a href='?cv=ms-category&mode=2&id=$ctgr_id'>link</a>";

                $dataRows = $dataRows . "**row**" . $ctgr_name . "|";
                $dataRows = $dataRows . $remark . "|";
                $dataRows = $dataRows . $link;
            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
        echo '<div id="draw-grid" class="tbl-responsive" style="overflow-x:auto;"><script>DrawTable("draw-grid","'.$dataRows.'");</script></div>';

//javascript
function DrawTable(Container,dataRows)
{
    dataRows =  dataRows.split(ROW_SPLITTER);
    var tTable=$('<table>');
    //draw the table header
    tTable.append(drawHeader(dataRows[0])); 
    //draw the table body
    tTable.append(drawBody(dataRows));
   //add table to wrapper container first and then add into the parent  container
    $('<div>').append(tTable)
          .appendTo($('#'+Container));
    return;
}
function drawHeader(headerRow)
{
    var headerRowColumns = headerRow.split("|");
    var tblRow=$('<tr>');
    headerRowColumns.forEach(function(element,index) {
        $('<th>')
        .text(element)
        .appendTo(tblRow);  
    });
    return $('<thead>').append(tblRow);
}
function drawBody(objRows)
{
    var tBody=$('<tbody>');

    objRows.forEach(
    function(objRow,index) 
    {
        if(index!=0)
        {   
            tBody.append(drawBodyRow(objRow,index));    
        }
    });
    return tBody;
}

function drawBodyRow(bodyRow,rowIndex)
{
    var bodyRowColumns = bodyRow.split("|");    
    var tRow=$('<tr>');

    bodyRowColumns.forEach(function(element,columnIndex) 
    {
        $('<td>').text(element).appendTo(tRow);
    });
    return tRow;
}
```

Comment: Your `DrawTable` function must be escaping the HTML tags.

Comment: `<button>` inside an `<a>` tag is invalid HTML

Comment: @kerbholz i think it is not a problem because I already removed it but still showing as normal character.

Comment: @Nick I will also add that "DrawTable" function in my question. so you can see it.

Comment: Right, it isn't a problem related to your question, but still remains invalid HTML

Comment: @kerbholz ok noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('<td>').text(element).appendTo(tRow);
```

In this line and others like it, you're setting the inner *text* of the matched elements to be a value.

This is actually a good thing in almost all cases.  You don't want to be interjecting arbitrary HTML into a context where a text value is intended.  Otherwise, you open up yourself to potential security issues, or at least, invalid HTML.

What you should be doing instead, if you really intend to inject HTML, is to append those elements to this one.

Your code has other problems too...

```
$link = "<a href='?cv=ms-category&mode=2&id=$ctgr_id'>link</a>";
```

In this line, you're interpolating arbitrary data into a URL *and* into HTML, with nothing being escaped.  Use `http_build_query()` to escape the data for the query string.  Then, be sure to use `htmlspecialchars()` for any arbitrary data injected into HTML to ensure it's escaped for that context.

Comment: thanks for your helpful answer.
I just changed my code as below:  
if (columnIndex == 2){$('<td>'+element).appendTo(tRow);}